# Angular not working for spfx webpart

Tags: spfx, angularjs, sharepoint-framework

I am trying to load angular in my Sharepoint online custom master page(CDN referenced only once), and have added SharePoint framework web part on the page. But none of the angular operation of web part working. And I am getting this error in console:

> WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.

What could be the possible issue and resolution for this?

Comment: How about you share your actual code so we dont have to take guesses on the problem.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to load angular two times(Masterpage and your web part)?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to like you are trying to load angular in two times.

Add the following lines in your web part to check whether angular is loaded or not.

```
if(!angular) {
    //load angular file
}
```

Note: If you loaded angular in master page means, mostly no need to load angular again in web part, until you these web parts in system master pages